# Using StackPanel as ContentControl (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, stackpanel

So I have a StackPanel that I am using as a ContentControl.  I have a place where I want buttons to be generated based on data that I am binding to, and that is all working good, but I want the buttons to be laid out horizontally, not vertically as is what is currently happening.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

And here is the code from my ContentTemplate description:

```
<StackPanel Name="wpReleaseButtons" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
    <ItemsControl IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BranchCommands}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Tag="{Binding}" Padding="3">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayValue}" />
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Any info would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say it looks like the `ItemsControl` is what is displaying the buttons vertically. if you want the buttons in the `ItemsControl` to be horizontal, then you need the `StackPanel` to be in the `ItemsControl` `ItemsPanelTemplate`, not the other way round like what you have in your code:

```
<ItemsControl IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BranchCommands}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Tag="{Binding}" Padding="3">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayValue}" />
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I might be slightly wrong on the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` bit as I haven't got any data to test it with...

**Edit:** In addition to the Bea reference, there's some good stuff by [Dr WPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/28/Default.aspx).

Comment: This did it!!!  Thanks for the answer, and I've bookmarked Bea's site as well.  Thanks everyone!  This was starting to bug me quite a bit, lol.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see your image (it's blocked by my company's firewall), but here I go anyways...

Your 'Orientation="Horizontal"' is probably working as it should: it only contains one child element, an ItemsControl. Instead, try making a ControlTemplate for your ItemsControl, where the ControlTemplate contains a StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal".

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Once again, Bea comes through with an answer/example!

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=10